# How to show form using onClick/hover combination without hiding it when uploading an image with cakephp

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I want a button that shows up when hovering over my image, then when I click the button I want a form to appear, but I do not want it to disappear when I click 'choose file'

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#profile_pic, #edit_pic").hover(
   function(){
      $('#edit_pic').removeClass('hidden');
   }
);
$("#edit_pic").click(function (){
 $("#upload_form").removeClass('hidden');
});

</script>

<html>

<div id="profile_pic">
</div>

<div id="edit_pic">
</div>

<div id="upload_form">
  //upload image form using cakephp
            <?php 
            echo $this->Form->create('Account', array('enctype' => 'multipart/form-data', 'url' => array('controller' => 'images', 'action' => 'before_crop', 'accounts' , $current_user['id']))); 
            echo $this->Form->input('image_relpath', array('type' => 'hidden'));
            echo $this->Form->input('Account.image', array('type' => 'file', 'label' => false));
            echo $this->Form->end('Upload');
         ?>&nbsp;
</div>

</html>
```

I cannot tell if my jquery is wrong or if the cakephp is automagically messing things up, butas soon as I click "choose file" (a button created by the form), the whole form disappears.

Comment: When the form disappears, is the hidden class applied to the form again?

Answer (score 0):

I can easily spot some issues on your code.

First on HTML, don't forget to **open and close** quotes in tag's attributes.

Second, on your jQuery selector, when referring to an ID, never forget to use the *sharp symbol* **#**.

Try fixing them, and see what happens.

---

You can also use this example:

```
<style type="text/css">
#edit_pic, #upload_form {
    display: none;
}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript">
$("#profile_pic").mouseenter(function(){
    $("#edit_pic").show();
});

$("#edit_pic").click(function(){
    $("#upload_form").show();
});
</script>
```

Be careful, because in this way, the `#edit_pic` button will never disappear once it's shown.

Comment: no, I see why you might thing that would cause the issue, but I just did not copy/paste it. I typed it incorrectly. I will fix it on here so, that does not distract you from the real problem.

Comment: as soon as I click the button inside the form, the form disappears.

Comment: @CaraDrye the submit button of `#upload_form`?

Comment: no, cake creates a button that allows you to choose a file from your computer to upload. I also noticed that if you don't click anything, it disappears, so I figure out that adding "return false;" at the end of the .click function solves my problem. Thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing in your code to indicate why things are disappearing.  It's obvious your example is not complete.  If you can provide a complete example that would reproduce the errors you're encountering, we can try to find out what's wrong and solve the problem.

Comment: Have you worked with cakephp before? I creates a lot of the html for you. Everything is here. I solved the problem tho. Thanks anyways

Comment: I have not, though I did take a quick look at http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1383/Form.  It doesn't look like it generates any JS at all, so I'm still not sure how the form disappears.  Either way, glad you solved your problem.

Comment: it generates html. the js is all there.

Answer (score 0):

Adding "return false" to my .click function solved this issue.

```
$("#edit_pic").click(function (){
  $("#upload_form").removeClass('hidden')
  return false;
});
```

Comment: jQuery temporary functions are not suposed to return anything, your problem was not correctly solved. http://api.jquery.com/click/

Comment: "return false" keeps it from doing its default action.